# How to retrieve values from TextArea in a Local Variable in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, textarea

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

In a view, I have 2 DropDownList and TextArea and 2 buttons :

- DropDownList Poste
- DropDownList Fonction
- Button Ajouter
- Button Enregistrer
- TextArea

The Values of the TextArea are added from the DropDownList 'Fonction' when I click on the button 'Ajouter'.

I want to retrieve those values in a local variable. And that when the user click on the button 'Enregistrer'(submit).

This is the code of the view :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Store", "Fonction")) { %>
<h2>Gérer les droits</h2>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<fieldset><legend>Gestion</legend>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems)%>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Fonction :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedFonction, Model.FoncItems, new { @id = "ff" })%>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div><input type="button" value="Ajouter" id="aj"  onclick="addtext()"/></div>
        <br />
        <div>
        <textarea id="tt" cols="10"  name="S1" rows="8" readonly="true"></textarea>
        </div>
</fieldset>
<br />
<div><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="sv" /></div>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var storedValues = [];
    function addtext() {

        var ff = document.getElementById('ff');
        var tt = document.getElementById('tt');


        var selectedValue = ff.options[ff.selectedIndex].value + " ";
        if (storedValues.indexOf(selectedValue) === -1) {
            storedValues.push(selectedValue)
            tt.value = storedValues.join('')
        }

    }
</script>
```

and this is the code of the methode store (for the submit) in the controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Store(FlowViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Fonction_Poste FP = new Fonction_Poste();
                FP.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;
                FP.ID_Fonction = model.SelectedFonction;
                FP.Droit = 1;

                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea htaDemo = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea)(form1.FindControl("tt"));
                String Value = htaDemo.Value;

                db.Fonction_Postes.Add(FP);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

So as you see, Itried to do retrive values using this statement but that's didn't give any result :

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea htaDemo = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea)(form1.FindControl("tt"));
            String Value = htaDemo.Value;
```

Comment: Do you have any property in the `FlowViewModel` for the value of the text area to bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any property in the `FlowViewModel` for the value of the text area to bind to, you can use it.

> If you have any property with the name `S1`, the value of the text area will be automatically bound.

Because, in ASP.Net MVC, there are no server side controls that you can refer to. Everything is model bound automatically.

Else, you can either create a property or use the `FormCollection` to get the value and use it accordingly.

Please share your implementation related to this to guide better.

Comment: thx,,,yes I already did that and it' s works but not witth collection but with the request like this : var value1 = Request["S1"];

Comment: the problem now that the action didn't works (not saving in the base) when the script is functionnal

Comment: what exception are you getting.

Comment: I have a script that remove item selected from the dropdownlist when i submit(in order to throw eception of 2 primary key when saving in the base),,,It's works perfectly but only when the button is not binded to the Action Result Store

Comment: do you mean that the save reports duplicate primary key or primary key violation.

Comment: No, In order to not save 2 primary key with same value (it will be an error in the execution) : I protect that wiith the script that remove each item selected (each primary key saved),,,,but the problem the script and the action result didn' t works together

Comment: Okay. In that case you should remove the item from the collection before binding using the `Html.DropDownList`.

Comment: sorry but may i know how ??

Comment: Suppose you have a collection of items [duplicate primary key removed] from the controller, you can build a `SelectList` with the collection and then set it in the ViewData / ViewBag and then you can call `Html.DropDownList` with the name of the ViewData or the ViewBag.
`@Html.DropDownList("SelectedFonction", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["SelectedFonctions"])`

Comment: sorry for the late my friend,,,you mean i will replace my own selectlist with this collection

Comment: @anouar: No worries on the delay. We have to have a custom data source as some items are removed so that it will not affect other functions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30644/discussion-between-saravanan-and-anouar)